# QDockwindow next to QDockWindow

Tags: qt, qdockwidget

I'm using qdockwidget (Qt5.5.1) to do my screenmanagement, however I am looking for a way to have a dockwidget next to my other dockwidget so the configuration would be:

Mainwindow | dockwidget | dockwidget2

However I seem to only be able do dock my dock windows around the mainwindow. Is this feature possible with qdockwidget?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: [Riateche - Tool window manager](https://github.com/Riateche/toolwindowmanager)